# Почему заголовок не моргает?

Tags: javascript, html

```
<script>
function blink() {
var div= document.getElementById('greeting');
if (div.style.visibility =="hidden"){
    div.style.visibility =="visible";
} else {
    div.style.visibility =="hidden";
}
}
window.setInterval(blink,500);
 </script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="greeting"> 
Hello,Guys!
</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это происходит, потому что вы вместо знака присваивания (`=`) используете знак сравнения (`==`). Изменять стиль нужно именно знаком `=`:

```js
function blink() {
  var div = document.getElementById('greeting');
  if (div.style.visibility == "hidden") {
    div.style.visibility = "visible";
  } else {
    div.style.visibility = "hidden";
  }
  console.log(div.style.visibility);
}
setInterval(blink, 500);
```

```html
<div id="greeting">
  Hello,Guys!
</div>
```